# SSRS C# mapping RDL throws the error

Tags: c#, deployment, ssrs-2008, datasource, rdl

I am mapping the Reports(RDL) with data sources through C#.

I am getting the Below error

The path of the item '' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidItemPathException: The path of the item '' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash.

Any pointers

Thanks,
 Sai

Comment: How about showing the code that's producing the error so we can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Pete is spot on. This is probably a typo in your path. We could help you but only if you show us the code producing the error.